# Deploy Django 1.7 application to Apache2 with WSGI

Tags: python, django, linux, apache, mod-wsgi

I am trying to deploy an old Django application (1.7) to the Apache2 server on Debian. I am finally able to run the app with `./manage.py runserver` but I had no success in getting the `mod-wsgi` working. I've never written a server-side application in Python so I may be missing something obvious.

These are the steps I followed

1. Everything I tried is with `/usr/bin/python` which is 2.7 - I know, I should be using `virtuelenv` but I didn't want to add even more complexity to the whole thing (since I am not familiar with it)
2. installed `mod-wsgi` with `apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi`
3. Add following config to the /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/wsgi.conf
4. Apache2 restart

```
<IfModule mod_wsgi.c>
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/rosasystem.pl/public_html/rosasystem/rosasystem/wsgi.py
    WSGIPythonHome /usr/bin/python
    WSGIPythonPath /home/rosasystem.pl/public_html/rosasystem
    LogLevel warn

    <Directory /home/rosasystem.pl/public_html/rosasystem/rosasystem>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Order deny,allow
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

Since then, I keep getting this error message in the `error.log` - most of the stuff I've googled suggests that there is a Python version discrepancy between `mod-wsgi` and system/virtualenv Python version which in this doesn't make sense because everything is Python 2.7.

```
[Tue Oct 06 15:13:42.946626 2020] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 17059:tid 139874785088640] AH00489: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 OpenSSL/1.1.1g mod_wsgi/4.6.5 Python/2.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Oct 06 15:13:42.946650 2020] [core:notice] [pid 17059:tid 139874785088640] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Tue Oct 06 15:13:42.951277 2020] [wsgi:warn] [pid 17061:tid 139874785088640] mod_wsgi (pid=17061): Python home /usr/bin/python is not a directory. Python interpreter may not be able to be initialized correctly. Verify the supplied path.
[Tue Oct 06 15:13:42.951531 2020] [wsgi:warn] [pid 17062:tid 139874785088640] mod_wsgi (pid=17062): Python home /usr/bin/python is not a directory. Python interpreter may not be able to be initialized correctly. Verify the supplied path.
ImportError: No module named site
```

At this point, I am pretty much stuck; what new things can I try?

Comment: Have you tried it without the WSGIPythonHome since you are using system python?

Comment: @WombatPM yes, I have, with no chage

Comment: Did you try adding  /usr/lib/python2.7 to the WSGIPythonPath?  And were there any errors when you ran pip install -r requirements.txt  ?

Answer (score 2):

`site-packages` path should be added to `WSGIPythonPath`, just get the correct path for your system

```
<IfModule mod_wsgi.c>
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/rosasystem.pl/public_html/rosasystem/rosasystem/wsgi.py
    WSGIPythonHome /usr/bin/python
    WSGIPythonPath '/home/rosasystem.pl/public_html/rosasystem;/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages'
    LogLevel warn

    <Directory /home/rosasystem.pl/public_html/rosasystem/rosasystem>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Order deny,allow
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: WSGI is definitely missing the path to python library based on the import fail.

Comment: I'll try in a moment